# ¿Cómo establecer formato condicional en hojas de cálculo de Google, tomando como referencia Intervalos diferentes al intervalo aplicado?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas, formato-condicional

**Entorno:**

- Navegador Web Google Chrome Versión 47.0.25
- Hoja de cálculo Google spreadsheets

**Situación**

Estoy tratando de que la celda I1, cambie de color solo cuando IJ sea mayor que J1, al elegir la condición no aparece la opción de relacionar otras celdas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trato de realizar la configuración utilizando la opción “La fórmula personalizada es” sin éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con `=I1>J1`.

Te faltó el signo igual (`=`) al inicio de la fórmula.

**Referencias**

[Aplicar reglas de formato condicional - Ayuda de Editores de Documentos de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=es)